# select inside dollar signs in latex using vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

How to select everything inside `$math_formula_here$` in vscode when writing latex?

I have tried shift+alt+rightarrow but it does not work.

Comment: Related: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#SelectionRangeProvider and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/latex

Comment: I'm using [LaTeX Workshop](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop) which is a more comprehensive extension. About the API reference, I don't know what should I do with it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by)

Add the following key binding

```json
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+right",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "selectby.regex",
    "when": "editorLangId == latex"
    "args": {
      "backward": "$",
      "forward": "$",
      "forwardInclude": false,
      "backwardInclude": false
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out, but I'm looking for something more native.